# How to solve $y'' = f(y,y')$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm a BC student and I want to solve $yy'' +y'^2+yy'^2 = 0$, here are my thoughts and way for finding a general solution:

1. this is not linear so I can't use the Laplace transformation.
2. here it is:
   $$
   yy'' +y'^2+yy'^2 = 0 \Rightarrow \frac{y''}{y'} + \frac{y'}{y} + y' = 0
   $$
   $$
   \Rightarrow ln(y')+ln(y)+y = c_1 \Rightarrow y'ye^y = c_2 
   $$
   so now I have to solve $y'ye^y = c_2$ that's it:
   $$
   y'ye^y = c_2 \Rightarrow ye^yd_y = c_2d_x \Rightarrow (y-1)e^y = c_2x + c_3 
   $$
   and Bingo!

my question is that is there any better way of solving this type of DEs? because my way doesn't seem to be a general way of solving. in other words, if the equation was $y^2y'' +y'^2+yy'^2 = 0$ my way of solving didn't work out and I feel lucky in this equation.

How do you solve $y'' = f(y,y')$ type problems? are there any tricks or other better methods? thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This differential equation is [of the type](https://math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/ode/second/reduc1/reduc1.html)

$$y'' = f(y,y').$$

You can try to solve it by using $y'(x)=v(y(x))$ as substitution, which implies

$$y'' = \dfrac{dv}{dy}\dfrac{dy}{dx}=v'y'.$$

Hence,

$$v'y' = f(y,y') \implies v' = \dfrac{f(y,v)}{v}.$$

For your equation it is

$$v' = \dfrac{1+y}{y}v$$

which is separable.

Comment: $v'y'$ is ambigous notation. Don't write it like that.

Comment: @Dylan: You are right. But the second line should make clear what is meant by $v'$ and $y'$.